# How to prevent System.Windows.Forms.Form from stopping Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I have thoses classes

```
using System.Windows.Forms

public class Tata : Form
{
    int titi;
}

[Serializable]
public partial class Toto : Tata
{
    int toto;
}
```

but whenever I try to build my project an exception is thrown because apparently Form does not support the serialization.

Is there any way to avoid Form to be serialized and thus avoiding the error ?

Comment: Why are you tring to serialize a Form?

Comment: @DarrenYoung and NicolasR: Inheriting from Form does only make sense if you 1.) want to make a windows Forms projec or 2.) customize your dialog or 3) is kinda second, but anyway: making your custom control

Comment: I am making a Windows Forms project (I did not post the full class that is having a problem, because it would be to big for just an example)

Comment: I just created a new WinForms project and made the same code you are using and there is no exception     public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var t = new Tata();
            t.Name = "adfasd";
        }
    }

    public class Tata : Form
    {
        private int titi;
    }
    [Serializable]
    public partial class Toto : Tata
    {
        private int toto;
    }

Comment: So, currently you're entangling your *data* (information that you would want to persist) with your *presentation* (the means by which you display information on screen). You'll not make this work whilst the two are so entangled.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever okay thanks, so I need to find a new way to make my data persistant

Comment: Typical case of http://xyproblem.info/ ? Could it be that you want to serialize your data, don't know how to, try to serialize the form instead, and now are asking about problems with that?

Comment: I'm just new on a project which work that way (Toto inherit from Tata which inherit from Form) and my task was to make the data in Toto persistant (and since other parts of the project are already using the serialization, I figured I would serialize Toto as well)